# Spring boot same API but different return type of byte[] and json

Tags: spring-boot, rest, controller, httpresponse, content-negotiation

I want the capability to send the JSON list like List if the request Accept Header is of type application/json, but send it in a byte array(avro format) if the request Header is of type application/avro. This should be for the same REST endpoint like /something/employee. Can I have the same method but different return types, will Spring Boot look at the accept header and correctly decide on which method to call?

What should be the return type? Can it be a ResponseEntity without any type?

Comment: I think it should be possible with [content negotiation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml). What I did when I needed to return both XML and JSON, I declared what my API produces `@GetMapping(value = "something", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })`, and register XML converter in my `@Configuration`. Also, I returned `ResponseEntity<SomethingDto>`.

Comment: Yes, I saw examples of those, but in this case my response is either byte[] array or a POJO list that gets converted to JSON. If I just return a list of POJO, it works fine for json, but it doesn't convert those to byte array in Avro format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your method to simply return a naked `ResponseEntity` and check the value of the `Accept` header to determine what to return

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity getContentNegotiateResponse(@RequestHeader("Accept") String accept) {

    SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();

    if (accept.equalsIgnoreCase(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(someObject));
    } else if (accept.equalsIgnoreCase("application/avro")) {
        byte[] value = "SomeData".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(value));
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
}
```